# PHP, расширение scream, настройка

Tags: php, документация

Вот [страница описания настройки](http://php.net/manual/ru/scream.configuration.php) расширения scream.

Английским по почти белому написано:

> scream.enabled int
>
> Whether or not to enable scream.

Для разрешения "scream"... Whether or not!?!?

Что они имели в виду? Какое значение туда подставлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неплохо у них там с юмором. 
Подставляйте то, что вам больше понравится из пары: 1/0, Yes/No, On/Off, или True/False

Comment: Больше всего меня смущает, что оно integer. Может там побитовая маска какая, определяющая уровни ошибок, про которые будет кричать.

Comment: Ну строго говоря формулировка "Whether or not to enable" подразумевает логическое включить / отключить, так что других вариантов быть не может. А так да, странно что не boolean.